# How do I set up a redirection for a video file?

Tags: redirect

I sent some people a link to a video file on my website:

```
https://www.example.com/videos/examplevideo.mp4
```

I've since added that video to YouTube, and would like when they click on the above link for them to be redirected to the YouTube video.

Is that possible, and if so, how please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on the webserver that you are running. If it is Apache (many hosted sites are), then you can add a .htaccess file to your root folder with the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    Redirect /videos/examplevideo.mp4  https://your.youtube.link [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

The R=301 says this is a permanent redirect, so their browser can remember it.
The L says this is the Last instruction, so if the incoming condition is met no other rewrrite rules will execute (in this case there are no others anyway).

If you don't have root access then you may need the support team on on your host provider to do this.

Comment: Thanks AntG, but that's throwing an internal server error. "Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@hooklust.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Comment: I checked the video link on the site, and it's correct, and there redirect URL is too. If I take the redirect out and just have the RewriteEngine On command in, the site loads ok, so there's something in the Redirect doing it. I have other domains on the server that have htaccess files, so I'm sure it's Apache

Comment: It might be to do with the link being directly to an .mp4 and the redirect being to a webpage.  Try a different test redireting a page link to another?